# how can add special characters to keys of array

Tags: php, arrays, array-walk

I want add special character to keys of my array, like this example.
how can i convert this array

```
$tmp = array(
"name" => "aya",
"number" => "10");
```

to

```
$tmp = array(
"[name]" => "aya",
"[number]" => "10");
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? It seems you are trying to fix another problem with that...

Comment: What is the problem with the latter code? Do a `print_r ($tmp);` and it seems to return working results.

Comment: I use `str_replace(array_keys($tmp), array_values($tmp))` for change `[name]` to 'aya'.  
but where get array from database, my array have `name` key and no `[name]`, and now i want name and number to `[name]` and `[number]`

Comment: It's perhaps not elegant, but is it so hard to write a plain loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
foreach ($tmp as $key=> $value) {
    unset($tmp[$key]);
    $tmp["[$key]"] = $value;
}
```